# CORS error using Yii2 API and ReactJS frontend

Tags: reactjs, rest, yii, yii2

This question might seem very easy to someone use to Yii2 API and React Js. I am quite new combining this technology.

I have a Yii2 API with the behaviors configured as shown here

```
public $serializer = [
    'class' => 'yii\rest\Serializer',
    'collectionEnvelope' => 'items',
];

public static function allowedDomains()
{
    return [
       '*'   // star allows all domains
       'http://localhost:3000',
    ];
}  

public function behaviors()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::behaviors(), [

            // For cross-domain AJAX request
            'corsFilter'  => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
                'cors'  => [
                    // restrict access to domains:
                    'Origin'=> static::allowedDomains(),
                    'Access-Control-Request-Method'    => ['POST','GET','PUT','OPTIONS'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => false,
                    'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,// Cache (seconds)
                    'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => false,

                ],
            ],

        ]);
    }
```

when I use fetch request on this API using GET, It works perfectly well and returns the data to my reactjs frontend.

Now, I am trying to implement a signup to my application where I need to send data from my frontend using POST to my API.(I have implemented my signup action and it works well with postman.) When I try to make a post request to this API, I get the error , (CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing) on my console. Below is my Reactjs request and I do not really know what I am missing. Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

```
//this function is to save data to the API
saveUser = (user) => {

    fetch(URL_SIGNUPUSER, {
    method: 'post',
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        //'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': "*"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
                          name:user.name,
                          username:user.username,
                          email:user.email,
                          password:user.password,
                        })
    }).then(res=>res.json())
    .then(()=>{
        this.setState({
            user: { name:'',
                    username:'',
                    email:'',
                    password:'',
                    confirm_password:'',
                },
            success:true,
            error:false
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * and can you see if the response headers have access control headers

Comment: You need to set `withCredentials=true` for request and also on server set CORS filter to `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials = true`. This will enable sending cookies (such as PHP session cookie). However, this also disallows origin for all domains to conform with the specification, so instead of `Origin => [*, "domain.com"]` you must set only one origin domain. See https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ or https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. The request should also comply with CORB policy (mime type etc).

Comment: thanks  so much the  error was rectified. I discovered that in when you are using a POST in an action then you return data,  you need to set the Action as POST and OPTIONS.. when I did that, it worked